# android application icon id

Tags: android, icons

I need to display notification in the status bar with the application icon. 
but i didn't find any way to retrieve the application icon id ?
(I currently use the 1.5 SDK)

Answer (score 0):

try using [getApplicationIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29) from PackageManager.

Comment: it returns a Drawable, I need an id (for the notification object)

Answer (score 0):

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Actually, this is wrong.  The icon may not be called "icon".  This way is better:

`context.getApplicationInfo().icon`